# Linux partition scheme

Tags: partitioning, user-space

Im NEW to linux . I want to install ubuntu on my laptop , but l'm very confusion about partition scheme , i have searched a lot for this but didn't get any proper , easy and straight forward solution  ..  on my other windows laptop there is thee drive .. One is "C:" .. other one is for my personal use and the third one is for music , movies etc . I want that same THREE partition in ubuntu ..  I have 1TB Hard disk on my machine and i have no plan to run two OS on my same machine .. I want only ubuntu on my machine with three drive ( one for my personal use second one for music and movie etc .. And third one for installing new software and packages like "c:" drive on window ) which cover up all my space .

I want straight forward answer according to my requirement with little explanation  .. Like "root should have 200-300 gb which behave same as "c:" on windows ....  etc ... " .

Comment: What you don't want to learn is exactly what you *must* learn. For starters, Windows terminology is irrelevant here. What you call drives are most likely partitions and those you can most likely keep provided you make space for / (ROOT) (OS and software) and SWAP. All other partitions (NTFS formated, presumably) won't be touched unless you tell the installer to do so.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the need of /home partition in Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/755781/what-is-the-need-of-home-partition-in-ubuntu) and possible duplicate of [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation) You need 3 partitions: a root partition for the OS and new software & packages, a swap partition, and a home partition for music and movies, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Windows does is that it takes all (If you have more than one) of your physical hard-drives and partitions them. Your C:// drive is just a partition. So are your other drives. When you put music in your E:// drive, for example, it is writing the music to your drive partition labeled E://, even though it is probably on the same physical drive. If you have more than one drive, it takes each of those drives and makes the partition for it the whole drive.

On Linux, all of your physical drives are combined into one big "drive" (actually your computer) called "/", but split up differently inside itself in /media/YourName/. For example, I have two drives, an SSD and an HDD. My SSD is my boot device and my HDD can be found at /media/adamthedog/*UUID*.

So, you see, Windows drives aren't actually drives, so you'd have to custom partition drives on Ubuntu to get your desired effect of multiple drives.

Answer (score 0):

During installation of ubuntu you will be asked to do a full hard drive wipe OR create a new partition along the current 
operating system.

Comment: That i know .. But in linux which partition behave like windows partition i have mention above ?? Like root behave like "c:" ..

Comment: None! Stop thinking Windows. Linux is different. And that I actually explained in my comment above.